# Enabling AndroidX for Google Maps Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

I'm trying to add a simple map activity to an existing Android App and when I try to add the activity "Google Maps Activity" is greyed out:

[image]

Opening SDK manager AndroidX is not listed :

[image]

Where/how do I add AndroidX ?

Enabling AndroidX is not described here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Have you tried "... you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar."  (from same source)

Comment: @Andy thanks, that did the trick once I migrated and rebuilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform refactor as per Andy comment:

[image]